# Getting socket timeout exceptions while receiving message from SQS queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sockets, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Need help with this socket timeout exception that I keep getting **intermittently** in my application while trying to read messages from AWS SQS queues.

**Process:**

1. I keep calling SQS queue receive message request with default wait message time of 20 seconds. (AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage)
2. If no message was received in above request another call is made to SQS to again poll the queue (same receive message request).

**Issue:**

Intermittently in my application, I get the following exception in SQS receiveMessage requests:

```
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient:executeHelper:492 - main - INFO : 
Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
```

By checking SQS queue from the console I see that during the failures a message is read from the queue (**message goes in flight**) but is not received at the application end. This leads to message getting locked for the visibility timeout period (1 hour) and hence a delayed processing of the message.

**Additional details:**

1. waitTimeSeconds for ReceiveMessageRequest is SQS default of **20 seconds**.
2. Socket timeout for the request is AmazonHttpClient's default **50 seconds**. (Exception is also seen after 50 seconds from previous read)
3. Max number of messages to be received in a request is set to **10** messages.
4. AWS SDK version used : **1.10.24** (aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.10.24.jar)

Any help around how to resolve or debug this further is greatly appreciated. Let me know if any further details are needed.

Comment: Where is this code running?  In EC2?  External server?  Inside an app on a user device?  My initial impression is that this would be a network-related issue, so where the code is actually running seems relevant.  I'm unfamiliar with this particular SDK, so the question arises as to whether your code is new or old, and whether the issue itself has been around since the code was deployed or is a new issue with code that historically worked correctly.

Comment: hi @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for your reply. The application is running in a EC2 instance only, so my guess is that network shouldn't be a big issue. The SDK we are using is actually a bit old (Oct, 2015) and we have been seeing this issue for quite a while now.

Comment: Maybe check the IAM role on Ec2

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue?